# TimerTrigger azure function does not trigger if I move the schedule to local.settings.json

Tags: c#, azure-functions, timer-trigger

Below works

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
          log.LogInformation($"Function function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");         
    }
```

But, this does not

```
   {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
       "Values": {
          "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
          "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
          "EmailScheduleTriggerTime": "0 */15 * * * *" //Run every  15 minutes
         }
  }


    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%EmailScheduleTriggerTime%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
         log.LogInformation($"Function function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");     
    }
```

It's not showing any error! This issue is seen only post-deployment to the azure.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any problem with your example. You may want to edit your post to provide a minimally reproducible code sample. As in, there should be something in the `Run()` method, even if it's only logging.  I am able to use a TimerTrigger with the ncrontab expression in the local.settings.json just fine.

Comment: Issue is only after deploying to the azure portal

Comment: What are your Azure Functions App Settings?  List relevant key names.

Comment: @kudlatiger I have the same problem. It used to work when I was using Azure Function 3. But after migrating to Azure Function 4 this stopped working.

What azure function version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

We have tried on our local to reproduce the issue, Below are the steps we have followed

- Created Azure function with timer trigger which will trigger in every 15 minutes using,
  ***[**`cron expression`**](https://crontab.guru/every-15-minutes)*** `*/15 * * * *` (***which will run every 15th minute***).

`local settings.json`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "EmailScheduleTriggerTime": "*/15 * * * *"
  }
}
```

`function1.cs`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace azfunctiontimer
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("%EmailScheduleTriggerTime%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

***FUNCTION TRIGGER THRIVING AFTER 15 MINUTE***:-

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [***Blog***](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/10/14/timer-triggered-azure-functions/).

Comment: locally it works. But after deploying to the azure portal it does not work.

Comment: As you have not mentioned in question so think may be you are facing it on local. Okay let me check and get back here after deploy.

Comment: Could you please try to add in configuration (Application setting) > Name `EmailScheduleTriggerTime` and value `*/15 * * * *` and save then goto overview tab make restart of your function app and check the function logs in monitor it should be trigger as per the specified time. [Check this image for reference](https://i.imgur.com/zbWFUpv.png)

Comment: it's already present in the configuration. How do we log "%EmailScheduleTriggerTime%", so that I can check if it's really picking the value or not?

Comment: Yes we can do that Go to function> Monitor and from their you can check the logs if its timely trigger or not

Comment: Please check this for [reference](https://i.imgur.com/V7r3Ksi.png)

Comment: For more information to create and deploy function app to Azure step by step guidance can be found here [***AzureLessons***](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-create-azure-functions-time-trigger-from-visual-studio-2019/)

Comment: Hi@ *kudlatiger*
  Have you checked the logs as given in reference image ,To get to know if the function is trigger or not.

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT Azure Functions does not use crontab expressions. They use [NCrontab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) expressions.  You should be using a 6 part ncrontab expression for Azure Funcitons.

Comment: example of 6 part ncrontab?

Comment: Hello @*kudlatiger*, Here is the example of [**NCRONTAB**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions) for azure function .

Comment: Yes @Adam Vincent you are correct. I was using it on local .Post deploy to azure get to know . If the answer and suggestions was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had the same problem when running functions v4 on Azure.

But after renaming the variable name to all **lower case** it started to work just fine.

So try change to:

```
"emailscheduletriggertime": "*/15 * * * *"
```

and

```
TimerTrigger("%emailscheduletriggertime%")
```